# proving polynomial root

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that $p(x)=6x^4+4x^3-2x^2-x-\pi$ has a root in the interval $[-2,0]$

I was reading an analysis book, and run onto this practice problem, I spent some time already trying to figure out how to do this problem and since the section where I found it does not show anything about polynomials or how to do problems like this one, I would really appreciated if anyone can help me with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does the section have any theorems about continuous functions?

Comment: yes, it has about continuous functions, I am just not sure how to use them in this problem

Comment: Which theorems?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Have you tried calculating the value of the polynomial at $x=-2$ and $x=0$?

Answer (score 2):

$$p(-2) = 3(-2)^4+4(-2)^3-2(-2)^2- (-2) -\pi = 48+24-8+4-\pi>0$$
$$p(0) = -\pi<0$$
By the intermediate value theorem, $p$ has a root in $[-2,0]$.

Comment: One or three roots, I think.